# How maven knows about my web app files vs servlet files?

Tags: java, maven

I created a simple Maven web app project, with 1 jsp file index.jsp. I am able to access this file from server as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/myProject/
```

How does it is able to access my index.jsp ? I haven't specified anything on web.xml. Where does all these configuration was exist ?

2.) Can I change the URL to like `http://localhost:8080/myProject/webapp/index.jsp` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), then everything located in the *Web application sources directory* (`src/main/webapp`) will be in the *root* of the application and will be public.

2. If you want to create `/myProject/webapp/index.jsp`, then create a `webapp` folder inside the `src/main/webapp` folder, so you will have folder structure like `src/main/webapp/webapp` *(Which I don't see any reason to use it that way)*. Then create the `index.jsp` inside it.

Comment: for example if I access like this /myProject/webapp/test, how does it know to look for a servlet or a jsp file ?\

Comment: If you create a servlet, then it will reserve the path that you define. If you have a servlet that has the /myProject/webapp/test path, the servlet will be called first, not the webapp content.